# Static Routing SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable

Tags: routing, ipv4, ip

How can I use 1.1.1.35 as gateway to reach 2.2.2.168/29 (.248) with the configuration below? I can ping 1.1.1.35 so it is reachable. When I traceroute it it uses gateway 1.1.1.1.

```
# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         1.1.1.1         0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
10.30.2.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.40.2.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.50.2.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.200.100 10.40.2.1       255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
192.168.200.101 10.40.2.1       255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
192.168.200.102 10.40.2.1       255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
1.1.1.0         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 eth1

# ip route list
default via 1.1.1.1 dev eth1 
10.30.2.0/24 dev eth0  scope link 
10.40.2.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.40.2.36 
10.50.2.0/24 dev eth0  scope link 
192.168.200.100 via 10.40.2.1 dev eth0 
192.168.200.101 via 10.40.2.1 dev eth0 
192.168.200.102 via 10.40.2.1 dev eth0 
1.1.1.0/27 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 1.1.1.10 

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ..... 
          inet addr:10.40.2.36  Bcast:10.40.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr .....  
          inet addr:1.1.1.10  Bcast:1.1.1.31  Mask:255.255.255.224
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

root@mymachine:~# route add -net 2.2.2.168 netmask 255.255.255.248 gateway 1.1.1.35
SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable

traceroute to 1.1.1.35 (1.1.1.35), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1)  0.224 ms  0.207 ms  0.194 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *

PING 1.1.1.35 (1.1.1.35) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 1.1.1.35: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.362 ms
```

Comment: Create a static route to 1.1.1.35 first.

Comment: Hello. I did actually try that (route add -host 1.1.1.35 gateway 1.1.1.1 dev eth1) but I still get "SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable"

Comment: host configuration is off topic here, you can ask this on [SF](http://serverfault.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use static routing, you need to provide the next hop to the destination, and `1.1.1.35` can't be the next hop from your host, since your host is not on the same network as `1.1.1.35`. You can't dictate a multihop path through a network from your host; you can only tell it the next hop to use, and the next hop must either be directly connected to the destination, or it must have a next hop toward the destination.

You have `1.1.1.1` as the default gateway, which will be used for any *off-net* destination (any destination *not* in the same network as `1.1.1.0/27`, which is your network on `eth1`). You can't use a gateway which is not directly reachable from your host because you can't get a layer-2 (MAC) address for a host or gateway not directly connected to your host.

You need to provide a route to `2.2.2.168/29` (which, by the way, doesn't include `2.2.2.248`) on the `1.1.1.1` gateway which points to `1.1.1.35`, assuming `1.1.1.35` is directly attached to `1.1.1.1`.